# Python TkInter - Assigning tags to indeterminate number of images

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on an application that displays a series of wallpaper images and allows the user to choose one as the app's background.

The application reads in a directory and displays all .JPG images in the directory. Thus, it needs to be able to allow the user to click on any option from a list of options of indeterminate length.

The problem is: clicking on any wallpaper in the list will just pass in the option to change to the very last wallpaper in the list (that is, the loop variable iterates, and I want the method called to capture the value of the loop variable at the iteration that I assign the tag).

Here is the relevant chunk of the code:

```
for i in range(0,(howManyWalls-1)):
    #Update position
    if i % 3 == 0:
        startX=x0+10
        startY=startY+160
    else:
        startX=startX+160

self.options.append(Image.open("../includes/wallpaper/wall"+str(i+1)+".jpg"))
self.options[i].thumbnail((150,150),Image.ANTIALIAS)
self.optionThumbs.append(ImageTk.PhotoImage(self.options[i]))
self.optionThumbsDisp.append(canvas.create_image(startX,startY,anchor=NW, image=self.optionThumbs[i]))
canvas.tag_bind(self.optionThumbsDisp[i],"<Button-1>", lambda x: self.changeWallpaper(canvas,w,h,(i+1)))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a frequent question asked when using lambdas.  The misconception is that the variable `i` inside your lambda function is in some way distinct from the variable `i` outside.  In other words, you're doing something like this:

```
i=3
def foo():
    print i
i=4
foo()  #prints 4, when you expected 3
```

In terms of regular functions, one way to "freeze" the value of i is to use a keyword argument since those are evaluated when the function is created:

```
i=3
def foo(i=i):
    print i
i=4
foo()  #prints 3, you're happy now.
```

The same thing can be applied to lambda functions:

```
canvas.tag_bind(self.optionThumbsDisp[i],"<Button-1>", lambda x,i=i: self.changeWallpaper(canvas,w,h,(i+1))
```

Now, (hopefully) it works.

Comment: @GregoryGay -- maybe I'll name this "Careful with closures, a cautionary tale" :^)